# Jest test fails if two methods are mocked

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, mocking

I have a confusing situation on my tests. See the code below.

*file.js*

```
class Test {
  constructor() {}

  async main() {
    const a = await this.aux1("name1");
    const b = await this.aux2("name2");
  }

  async aux1(name) {
      console.log(name)
  }

  async aux2(name) {
    console.log(name)
  }
}

module.exports = Test;
```

*file.spec.js*

```
describe('Concept proof', () => {
    const module = require("./file.js");
    const inst = new module();

    test('should call aux1', async () => {
        const a = jest.fn(() => "return");

        inst.aux1 = a
        inst.main()

        expect(a).toHaveBeenCalled()
    });

    test('should call aux2', async () => {
        const b = jest.fn(() => "return");

        inst.aux2 = b
        inst.main()

        expect(b).toHaveBeenCalled()
    });
});
```

*result*

```
    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0

      18 |         inst.main()
      19 |
    > 20 |         expect(b).toHaveBeenCalled()
         |                   ^
      21 |     });
      22 | });

      at Object.<anonymous> (file.spec.js:20:19)
```

The method aux2 is not invoked if aux1 is called from main, but behave as expected if I remove aux1 call from main.

I was not able to find an explanation for that behave on the docs. I'm misunderstanding something, or the normal behave should be aux2 be called even if aux1 is called before?
Any help will be appreciated!

Any help will be apreciated!

Comment: Why are you patching parts of the thing you're supposed to be testing? Also note that your tests leak state - `inst` is only created once, so over time more of its methods get replaced with mocks.

Comment: Just making the example simplier. I found no reason to bring more code than needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `await inst.main();`.

`inst.main()` is an asynchronous method. If `await` is not used, the main thread will continue to execute and will not wait for the completion of `inst.main()`.

This means the `expect(b).toHaveBeenCalled()` statement will be executed before `inst.main()` method.